# sprintf like function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have code in R and I want to convert that in python, I would like to know the function like **sprintf**. I have this query,

```
query1 = sprintf('''select * from table''',, toString(ids), df1, df2)
```

Comment: `query1 = f"select * from table {ids} {df1} {df2}"`

Comment: Do *not* construct SQL queries using string-formatting operations. Use whatever facilities your SQL library provides for constructing parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a % operator for this.

```
string = "A = %d\nB = %s\n" % (100, 1000)
print(string)
#output
A = 100
B = 1000
```

or fstring

```
string = f"A = {100}\nB = {1000}\n"
print(string)
```

or format

```
string = "A = {}\nB = {}\n".format(100,1000)
print(string)
```

Comment: Ooh it's been _so long_ since I've seen the interpolation operator. It's like an old friend come round to visit on holiday. That said: please don't ever use this anymore, it's been replaced not once but twice. f-strings are the modern solution here, with `str.format` as an option if you're running an older version of Python.